# What do the alarm chartevents exactly mean?

Tags: mimic-iii

An example:

- row_id 24288398,24288390 and 24288389 in table chartevents are all
  for the same patient.
- Itemid 224687 (row_id 24288398) shows the minute volume at charttime
  2101-09-12 17:00:00
- Itemid 220293 (row_id 24288390) shows the Minute Volume Alarm - High
  at charttime 2101-09-12 17:00:00 (same charttime)
- Itemid 220292 (row_id 24288389) shows the Minute Volume Alarm - Low
  at charttime (2101-09-12 17:00:00) (same charttime).

I thought that the alarm events occur then the special item values (here minute volume) undergoes or overgoes some border but how could it be that all three events (minute volume, Minute volume alarm - high and minute volume alarm - low) could appear at the same time?

Maybe my understanding of how the alarm events work is just wrong. So what is the interpretation of the alarm events (here for example Minute volume alarm - high and minute volume alarm - low)?

Comment: The itermids are different (220293 and 220292).  So we can have two alarms going off at the same time for two different quantities.  Isn't that quite possible?

Comment: That is of course possible, but exactly these itemids should not be the same I think because they are based on the same parameter:

220293 is "Minute Volume Alarm - High" and 
220292 is "Minute Volume Alarm - Low".

So they can't be set at the same time if they would be dependent from each other, right? 
Is it possible that these items are no alarm events but events that say "doctor / nurse xy changed the setting of alarm threshold high to 150 and low to 90" for example ? 
Because if these are only Setting-Events they could appear at the same charttime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are configurations for the alarm - not actual alarm events. So at that time you have the low alarm threshold = 2, the high alarm threshold = 18, and the actual value = 8.3.

Side note: if using ROW_ID, it's helpful to reference the version of MIMIC-III (i.e. v1.4) as it changes version to version.